# expected expression "implicit declaration of a function is invalid in c99"

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am using [this](https://github.com/thinkgaming/revenue-engine/blob/master/ThinkGaming/ThinkGaming/ReceiptValidation/VerificationController.m) receipt validation for testing purposes at this point, but Xcode is complaining about the lines

```
require(signature_length > offsetof(struct signature_blob, certificate), outLabel);
```

and

```
require(signature_length - offsetof(struct signature_blob, certificate) >= certificate_len, outLabel);
```

saying: "expected expression - implicit declaration of function 'offsetof' is invalid in C99"

how do I solve that?

Comment: `#include <stddef.h>`?

Comment: I use those just fine. The import I have is the usual `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

Comment: @maddy - you are a genius! please convert your comment to answer, so I can accept! THANKS How do you discover things like that? by Ouija board? unbelievable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the standard `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in your file will fix the problem.

Of course if you don't need any of the foundation classes, then do as others have said, include `stddef.h`.

Comment: My project is set up to use modules and because of that and probably because of another of the infinite bugs of Xcode (I hate Xcode with passion, by the way), I have discovered now that this solution works for development but not for release. In my case it just compiles if I include the Foundation framework, add this import line and also `@import Foundation`. Xcode is such a pathetic tool for development. Apple should buy AppCode, name it Xcode 6 and give it to us.

Answer (score 2):

`offsetof` is a macro contained in stddef.h. Add this line in your source file.

```
#import <stddef.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

That macro is defined in "stddef.h", so you should have the following line:

```
#include <stddef.h>
```